# Trigger something to open from an external link

Tags: jquery

Is it possible that some javascript or jquery can handle this:

I have an email campaign. I want one of the links in my email template to have some click event that when clicked, the target window will do something.

So I have two separate windows:

1. a link in an email that should trigger a click on target page
2. the target page has a link that will recieve event from the email link, and auto click this link and launch some popup ID.

Please `<a href="http://mysite.com" onClick="doSumthing();">click here</a>` to find out more about our product.

doSumthing() is expected to trigger some link in the target page to auto click launching some popups.

I think this type of things is already implemented by dangerous scam links :)

Any hint or example to achieve will surely clarify the clouds over my head, and always very much appreciated.

Thanks

UPDATE: It seems raising bad opinion :)
Its a school email to their student parents. The link is intended to simplify the access to a slideshow (colorbox) containing info about how to apply for school grades in a particular page. The slideshow is triggered from a small image that may be skipped by visitor, hence the need.

Comment: most email clients strip javascript from email messages

Comment: "I think this type of things is already implemented by dangerous scam links :)"  All the more reason not to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

javascript/html  aren't always executed in the email client. So that may not work as you wish.

But you could pass a parameter in the url, so the target page (if the parameter is set) could do what you want.

But again, automatic popups are block by some browser and users usually don't like them.

Comment: Thanks, the popup is just a slideshow showing some info for education purposes.